# Installing numpy, still problems

Tags: python, numpy, python-2.7

I followed the instructions at http://nltk.org/install.html.
My python version is 2.7.

When I try to do:

```
sudo pip install -U numpy
```

That doesn't work:

```
  File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 271, in check_types

    "Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to "\

SystemError: Cannot compile 'Python.h'. Perhaps you need to install python-dev|python-devel.
```

Any ideas to help me?

Comment: Perhaps you need to install `python-dev` or `python-devel`?

Comment: Wow! Well, I have never installed them for sure. How can I install them?

Comment: type `sudo apt-get install python-dev` in the command line

Comment: YEAH!!! Thank you a lot!! That was the issue! Thank you for your help!

Comment: I like how the problem was solved **by reading the message**.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by [User](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1320237/user) in the comments, executing

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

in the command line will fix this problem

Comment: What if you are in OSX?